# RabbitMQ permissions for Celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have multiple Celery clients for a single worker. The clients should be able to collect task results, so I used `backend="rpc://"`. To make it working, clients have config/write/read permissions `.*`, `.*`, `.*` over some vhost, that 's exactly what each tutorial has. Easy so far.

However, I don't know how to fulfill the following requirements:

- Clients should be only able to write into the task queues, without having permissions to read from it.
- `client_A` should not have access to the result queue of `client_B` and vice versa *(the result queues with randomized names like `1fe90fc4-8dce-3557-8e8d-6fbb2af9d4ee` are created automagically by Celery when I tell it to use RPC backend)*

How do I manage permissions on more precise than per-vhost level?

Comment: Upd: I had zero luck trying to find a proper solution. After some patching the celery app `.oid` on start and writing weird regex permissions, it was too much of a mess. Eventually I had to abandon Celery.